# python asyncio echo server with prompt for additional message

Tags: python, network-programming, python-asyncio

I have created a small echo server using python asyncio which support multiple client connections. Now I would like the option of adding some way for the server to have a prompt where I can send message to all the clients currently connected as well.
My idea is to have a prompt similar to what I have on my client side, and have that living in some other coroutine, but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to get access to the servers and actually send the messages in this separate coroutine.

Here is my current server code:

```
import asyncio

import aioconsole
import numpy as np

async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    global line
    while True:
        data = await reader.read(100)
        message = data.decode()
        addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
        print(f"Received {message!r} from {addr!r}")
        if message == 'quit':
            writer.write(message.encode())
            await writer.drain()
            writer.close()
            print("Closing connection to client.")
            await writer.wait_closed()
            break
        else:
            answer = f"answer={np.random.randint(0,10)}"
            print(f"Sent: {answer!r}")
            writer.write(answer.encode())
            await writer.drain()


async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    addrs = ', '.join(str(sock.getsockname()) for sock in server.sockets)
    print(f'Serving on {addrs}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

and here is my client code

```
import asyncio
from time import sleep

import aioconsole


async def tcp_echo_client():
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
        '127.0.0.1', 8888)
    while True:
        line = await aioconsole.ainput('Command me... ')

        print(f'Send: {line!r}')
        writer.write(line.encode())
        await writer.drain()

        data_b = await reader.read(100)
        data = data_b.decode()
        print(f'Received: {data!r}')
        if data == 'quit':
            print('Closing the connection')
            writer.close()
            await writer.wait_closed()
            break

asyncio.run(tcp_echo_client())
```